# Link to Google Play Application from an WEB PAGE

Tags: android, web, hyperlink, deep-linking

I know how to link users directly to product detail page in Google Play Application from an Android Apps using code below,

market://details?id=package_name

My question is, is there any way that link users directly to product detail page in Google Play Application from an WEB by force?
I tried with code below, however, few of devices ask me which app [web browser, Google play application] do I want to use to complete action of LINK but most of them usually links me directly to Google Play WEB Page.

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pacakage_name

Any Solution?

Thank you

Comment: what's the use case here? Why would a user need to see the web browser view rather than the native Google Play app view?

Comment: I have web page including GOOGLE STORE LINK for only mobile user. And want to take them to Google Play Application instead of Google Play Web Pages.

Comment: If the user has a device that gives them a choice of how to handle `market://` links, please allow the user to make their choice. After all, it is the user's device (not yours) and the user's battery (not yours) and the user's bandwidth (not yours). If the user does not wish to bother making a choice all the time, they can choose a default app for this particular request from the chooser.

Comment: So There is no way that it link users to Google Play Application instead of Google Play WEB ..by force.... from WEB PAGE [not IN Android App]...

Comment: > what's the use case here? //
Some users don't use their phone to read e-mails. I want to send an e-mail to suggest an app. I need the link to the App's page on the WEB, so they can review it on their preferred device - their computer.